# Creating an object from a JPanel class giving overflow error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, stack-overflow

I am trying to create an object from a class that extends JPanel but when i run it I get an StackOverflowError. 
Error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static int width = 600, height = 400;
public static String title = "tec9meister";

public static void createWindow(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    //createPane(frame);

    PaintPanel p = new PaintPanel();
    p.setSize(100,100);
    frame.add(p);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void createPane(JFrame frame) {
    PaintPanel pane = new PaintPanel();

    pane.setSize(width, height);
    pane.setFocusable(true);
    pane.requestFocus();

    frame.add(pane);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createWindow();
}
}
```

**PaintPanel.java**

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel{

public PaintPanel() {

    Target t = new Target(100, 100, 10, 10);

}
}
```

**Target.java**

```
public class Target extends PaintPanel {

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;

public Target(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}
```

Comment: The _full_ classes `PaintPanel` and `TestClass`, please. You clearly call some methods that aren't shown, and I'm pretty sure those or `TestClass` must be where the `StackOverflowError` is being thrown. Also, where is `Target` used?

Comment: Please show us the `TestClass` code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to create an instance of a class that extends PaintPanel within the constructor of PaintPanel, this will cause a StackOverflowError due to recursive calls of the same constructor. In particular, TestClass could not be Target since Target extends PaintPanel.

Comment: Thanks, i just made a method for creating the object and called it from the Main class and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

You should always run your Swing programs in the `Event Dispatch Thread`, using this:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            createWindow();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

If that doesn't solve it, try adding the `JPanel` to the frame's `contentPane`:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Comment: Those things clearly can't be causing a `StackOverflowError`, so can't be a solution or an answer. There is no evidence of the OP using `Thread`s, so there's no point to running Swing programs that way.

Comment: I've been told to always use the Event Dispatch Thread, even if there aren't any other threads. So it isn't necessary in these cases?

Comment: It could be considered good practice, as it makes it harder to forget to use it when you _are_ using threading, but I wrote working Swing programs long before I knew what `EventQueue` was without any problems (until I tried threading, ran into unexpected behaviour and looked this up).